# Isolated scope issue

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, isolation

I have almost no expertise when working with isolated scopes on angular but i found something for a project that i was using to check the strength of an username with an Angular directive.

This is the directive:

```
function usernameStrength() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      username: '=ngModel'
    },

    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

      /** Watch password fields **/
      scope.$watch('username', function(newVal) {
        scope.strength = isSatisfied(newVal && newVal.length >= 8) +
          isSatisfied(newVal && /[A-z]/.test(newVal)) +
          isSatisfied(newVal && /(?=.*\W)/.test(newVal)) +
          isSatisfied(newVal && /\d/.test(newVal));

        function isSatisfied(criteria) {

          return criteria ? 1 : 0;

        }
      }, true);
  }
}
```

Then on my HTML (JADE) i had an input and the directive on whom the strength progress bar is displayed and manipulated.

```
input.form-control(autocomplete="off", type='text', required='', ng-model="register.username")
```

label Strength
   username-strength(ng-model="register.username")

Till here everything works fine, but then if i add an object on the controller to store all the data from the form (which is a wizard) and set the input `ng-model` like this `ng-model="register.data.username"` (Same thing on the **username-strength** directive) Being **data** in the controller this object

```
vm.data  = {};
```

The $watches in the directive no longer have access to the input.

Comment: I would recommend creating a custom attribute to bind your scope to instead of the angular defined ng-model.

Comment: Thanks for guindance @dustmouse , any example on that approach?

Comment: I wonder why do people downvote a question without explaining the reasons behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your code, you are putting the username-strength on the label while the your directive is just triggered only for the element with name 'user-strength'. It is wrong way, so the $watch does not work.

1. The ngModel binds an input,select, textarea, not the label.
2. You have to modify the `restrict` to 'A' instead of 'E', and put it into the your  input[text]

[Fixed](http://plnkr.co/edit/lpOkbHJfE2FPQuBTiLQu?p=preview)

You are trying to track the status of text field username and print something like the strength of the text on the label. You can study on from this [sample](http://subarroca.github.io/ng-password-strength/). ([source](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-password-strength))